# Prove that if $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, $x \mid a$ and $y \mid b$. then $\gcd(x, y) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, $x \mid a$ and $y \mid b$. I want to prove that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.

From what I understand, I need to prove $a = xb$, for any positive integer $b$ # 0 (1) $b = ya$, for any positive integer $a$ # 0 (2), then I can prove that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.

I think I missed something to prove the formula of GCD before I can prove $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.

Comment: If $z$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $y$ it is also a divisor of both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know Bezout's lemma? That is , $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ if and only if there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax + by = 1$? This gives an easy proof. There is also a direct proof by the definition of gcd.

Comment: @DaBorn Why you have used the tag "linear-algebra"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this by contradiction. If $$\gcd(x,y)=d\ne 1$$then $$d|x|a\\d|y|b$$therefore $$d|\gcd(a,b)=1$$which is a contradiction and the proof is complete.

Comment: No proof by contradiction needed: Every common divisor of $x$ and $y$ is a divisor of $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition can be stated as follows:

> Let $x$ be a divisor of $a$ and $y$ a divisor of $b$. If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

I suggest we prove the contrapositive, which is to say we prove the logically equivalent proposition:

> Let $x$ be a divisor of $a$ and $y$ a divisor of $b$. If $\gcd(x,y)\neq 1$ then $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$.

So suppose $x$ and $y$ have a common divisor $d>1$. Use transitivity of divisibility.

Answer (score 0):

From the given,

$$a=mx=mp\gcd(x,y),\\b=ny=nq\gcd(x,y).$$

Hence

$$\gcd(x,y)|\gcd(a,b).$$